# How To Make UIPickerView components text to always fit?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, autosize

Let's say you have a UIPickerView and you want your text to always fit the given space its component gets (No "..." for misfitted text).

How to pull this off?

Comment: Can you provide sample code and include a list of solutions you've already tried?

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution:

Implement

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

in your picker delegate like this:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView)
    {
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        tView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
    }

    tView.text = [self pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
    //Add any logic you want here

    return tView;
}
```

This makes the labels to fit the text inside them perfectly.

Enjoy!